# Force a calculation result if less than zero to equal zero in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, numbers, rounding

Is there a built in VB function to ensure the following:

```
Dim price
Dim subsidy

if price - subsidy <= 0 then 
    price = 0
end if
```

In practical terms, I've lots of other things going on to calculate price, so I want to simplify this to:

```
Dim price = calculatedPrice - subsidy
```

and wrap that into some VB formatting that ensures if `price` ever becomes negative it's forced to zero.

I'm thinking that a simple type conversion might do it, but am not sure *which* type would suit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`Math.Max`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7x97k0y4.aspx#Y0) to do it:

```
Dim price = Math.Max(calculatedPrice - subsidy, 0)
```